# Determine the number of rows in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I know the range name of the start of a list - `1` column wide and `x` rows deep.

How do I calculate `x`?

There is more data in the column than just this list. However, this list is contiguous - there is nothing in any of the cells above or below or either side beside it.

Comment: Could you provide an example input, and an example of what you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Function ListRowCount(ByVal FirstCellName as String) as Long
    With thisworkbook.Names(FirstCellName).RefersToRange
        If isempty(.Offset(1,0).value) Then 
            ListRowCount = 1
        Else
            ListRowCount = .End(xlDown).row - .row + 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

But if you are damn sure there's nothing around the list, then just `thisworkbook.Names(FirstCellName).RefersToRange.CurrentRegion.rows.count`

Answer (score 62):

```
Sheet1.Range("myrange").Rows.Count
```

Comment: Given that `myrange` the OP has is *one cell* (the first cell of the list), this code will return 1 at all times. It's sad to see robot upvoting on completely wrong answers.

Answer (score 9):

Why not use an Excel formula to determine the rows?  For instance, if you are looking for how many cells contain data in Column A use this:

=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>")

You can replace <> with any value to get how many rows have that value in it.

=COUNTIFS(A:A,"2008")

This can be used for finding filled cells in a row too.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
Range( RangeName ).end(xlDown).row
```

to find the last row with data in it starting at your named range.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure that you probably wanted the answer that @GSerg gave.  There is also a worksheet function called `rows` that will give you the number of rows.

So, if you have a named data range called `Data` that has 7 rows, then `=ROWS(Data)` will show 7 in that cell.

Comment: hi wcm

thanks - GSerg's answer is the one I wanted.
The problem I had with the ROWS formula was that I didnt know the range address and I couldnt use a dynamic offset range using counta because there was more data in the column

Answer (score 1):

That single last line worked perfectly @GSerg.

The other function was what I had been working on but I don't like having to resort to UDF's unless absolutely necessary.

I had been trying a combination of excel and vba and had got this to work - but its clunky compared with your answer.

```
strArea = Sheets("Oper St Report CC").Range("cc_rev").CurrentRegion.Address
cc_rev_rows = "=ROWS(" & strArea & ")"
Range("cc_rev_count").Formula = cc_rev_rows
```