# Total number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

How do I determine the total number of used rows in my worksheet?

```
Dim rows As Integer
rows = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Rows.Count
```

---

I need to know so I can loop through all my rows:

```
For row = 1 To rows
    ' Check if row contains pattern.
    match = ReFind(Range(row & ":" & row), "^.*(\[KA\])|(\[KIC\])|(\[KS\])|(\[NA\]).*$")

    If match <> "" Then
        Call CopyRow(row)
    End If
Next row
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/114493/365102

Comment: I would not use "used range" for finding the last cell.  It is unreliable.  Try using:  `rows = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1],            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row`

Comment: I agree with Reafidy. Although I would use a range object to test that the `Find` is successful, else this code with fail on a blank sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` will return the last row used *in a particular column*, not necessarily the last row with any cell used.

---

Another way is to use `Sheet.UsedRange`  however you must be aware of certain limitations.

[`.UsedRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y166) returns a rectangular region bounding all used cells, so it may not be anchoured at cell `A1`.  To get the row number of the bottom of the range use

```
.UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
```

When deleting rows (or columns) `.UsedRange` may not update, therefore you may get a range larger than the true used range.

You can force an update: if you are happy to use `ActiveSheet` then  puting the line

```
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

in your code forces an update.

---

If you don't want to use `ActiveSheet` (for example in a routine passed a sheet as a parameter) then use:

```
i = Sh.UsedRange.Row
```

Don't rely on the value of `i` at this point. The next reference to `.UsedRange` will be the true used range.

Comment: I discovered `.UsedRange` 30 minutes after your post. :) But thanks for the detailed answer; I'm sure it will help any future visitors.

Comment: this code will also return the first cell in a column if the column is blank. So a row 1 result should be tested further to determine if it is truly used.